# Mailchimp API v2 or v3 finding subscriber in list based on a merge field

Tags: mailchimp

Example, we have a subscribers in a list that contain a USER_ID. I would love to search based on user_id. As in our user_id that we add to the list as a merge field, not the MD5 hash of the email that mail-chimp uses.

This is the request I have been doing:

Post to: `https://us2.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/helper/search-members`

JSON data:

```
{
    "apikey": "<MY API KEY>-us2",
    "query": "MERGE5:10070",
    "id": "<LIST ID>"
}
```

MERGE5 won't work at all. I can use MERGE0, MERGE1 and MERGE2 just fine but nothing after that. This might be a restriction from Mailchimp itself.

I tried using the defined names for those mergefields as well of course. Once again the names for merge0-2 work, but the names for anything after that do not.

Any help would be great!

Comment: This sounds like a question for support, since you're saying that one merge field isn't querying properly, but I'd advise against doing it this way. It's going to be a much slower query to run and doing it at any substantial volume could cause issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone runs into this, turns out the indexes on our list were bad. I talked to customer service through email and they were eventually able to re index our list and get it working. It was a weird issue.